# Vector XML element not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I have started development on Android 5.0. I'm reading about the vector drawables in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html.

When I add a vector drawable to my res/drawable folder, I get the message:

[image: Element vector must be declared]

I'm using the 21 release in all gradle build files and I'm using Android studio 0.8.13 (latest so far).

Anyone experiencing the same?

Comment: What is your `buildToolsVersion` in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug in the IDE. Command-line builds work fine, but Android Studio raises the error you report. This also occurs for 0.8.9 of Android Studio and `buildToolsVersion` of `21.0.1`.

I have filed [a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77700) that points back to this question.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare mentioned , it is a bug in IDE. This issue has been fixed in Android Studio 0.8.14 release.